# C++ GMP weird memory management

Tags: c++, memory, gmp

i am working with **GMP lib** for the first time and  it looks like this code does some dirty memory cheats:

```
void addition (const point p,const point q,const mpz_t fp, point* result){
    mpz_t ld;
    mpz_init(ld);
    lambda_add(p,q,fp,ld);

    gmp_printf( "WTFCHECK1:  %Zx, %Zx\n", p.x ,p.y);
    mpz_mul(result->x,ld,ld);
    gmp_printf( "WTFCHECK2:  %Zx, %Zx\n", p.x ,p.y);
    mpz_sub(result->x,result->x,p.x);
    gmp_printf( "WTFCHECK3:  %Zx, %Zx\n", p.x ,p.y);
...
}
```

where lambda looks like

```
void lambda_add (const point p,const point q,const mpz_t fp, mpz_t result){
    mpz_t ydiff,xdiff;
    mpz_init (ydiff);       
    mpz_init (xdiff);

    mpz_sub (ydiff,q.y,p.y);
    mpz_sub (xdiff,q.x,p.x);
...//no more usage of p or q
}
```

But program output still looks like this:

```
WTFCHECK1:  7cf27b188d034f7e8a52380304b51ac3c08969e277f21b35a60b48fc47669978, 7775510db8ed040293d9ac69f7430dbba7dade63ce982299e04b79d227873d1
WTFCHECK2:  de8a6886d284cb85d49a93b707475ed3d277242444ba9e860207f9a59a9ef351, 7775510db8ed040293d9ac69f7430dbba7dade63ce982299e04b79d227873d1
```

As you can see, **variable p.x** of type *mpz_t* (x and y are mpz_t type in *typedef structure point*) has changed without me assigning anything into it. What is the reason of this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: You may need to post the setup of `p`, `q`, and `result` as well as the call to `addition`. What happens if you comment out the call to `lambda_add`?

Comment: Can't say much without a MCVE. Note that you would likely save a lot of trouble if you used the header `<gmpxx.h>` that comes with GMP, and the type `mpz_class` it provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, :D problem was a bit on my side i was calling 
`addition (const point p,const point q,const mpz_t fp, point* result)` with same structure given as a point p and as a point* result, so along with modifying result i was also modifying point p. I appreciate your help anyway.